# understand positioning system in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm new to javascript and three.js, i'm trying to figure out how to get the 3d positions on a webpage.
for ex. i want to set a point light at (50,20,10) x,y,z values. how can I know that where this x,y,z values will come on a webpage?.I have seen code like below.

```js
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 10)
    light2.position.set(500, 100, 0)
    scene.add(light2)
```

I have googled but I didn't get enough information to sort out the things properly, can somebody help me with a good explanation or some article/tutorial link?

Comment: What do you mean the webpage has range -1 to 1?  You aren't putting a light in a webpage, you are putting it into a 3D world that will be rendered through WebGL and canvas.

Comment: @zero298 i googled 3d space in web and it showed that a webpage is always in that -1 to 1 range. i really don't know much about it, can you please help me to understand the 3d space in web?

Answer (score 0):

### Just a little background first...

- 3D space is infinite.
- The canvas is a viewport into that space.
- The size of the canvas on the page has no direct relation to anything in 3D space. You can double the size of the canvas, and all it does is make the rendered image bigger.

### To your question...

That's not to say you can't figure out where on the canvas a 3D thing might appear. You can project any point in 3D space into Normalized Device Coordinates with [`Vector3.project`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.project).

```js
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 10)
    light2.position.set(500, 100, 0)
    scene.add(light2)

// Where is it in NDC?
var ndc = new THREE.Vector3().copy( light2.position ).project( camera );
```

Normalized Device Coordinates range from `-1` to `1`, and represent the normalized width and height of the viewport with `(0,0)` at the center of the rendered image. So, you will need to convert them from NDC into pixel values on your canvas. (Also, you can ignore the `z` component, because the screen has no depth.)

```js
var canvasX = ( ndc.x + 1 ) * canvasWidth / 2;
var canvasY = ( ndc.y + 1 ) * canvasHeight / -2;
```